# Installing docker with devstack

Tags: installation, openstack, docker, devstack

I am trying to install devstack and docker (http://devstack.org/guides/single-machine.html) onto a VM containing Ubuntu 13.10 Server. devstack contains a docker installer script in tools/docker/install_docker.sh which it is recommended to run first before running the stack.sh installer script for devstack. I have patched the docker install script according to the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1237581 however docker still reports a problem:

socat[NNNN] E connect(3, AF=1 "/var/run/docker.sock", 22): Connection refused

Does anyone know a fix for this problem?
Thanks,
David

Comment: It looks like Docker is not running; use `ps aux | grep docker` to see if it has been started.

Comment: It appears to be running, I see: /bin/sh -e -c /usr/bin/docker -d /bin/sh    and    /usr/bin/docker -d   in the grep output.

Comment: Do you run it with `sudo`?
Please provide output of `ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: @Dmitriy I have run install_docker.sh both as sudo and without. In the latter case, I receive a "permission denied" error on docker.sock. As sudo, I receive the "connection refused" error, and `ls -l /var/run/docker.sock` generates: `srw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 14:29 /var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 1):

If you get error messages regarding /var/run/docker.sock then either the docker daemon/service is not started or your user (devstack user) has no permissions.

Start docker:

`service docker restart`

Add your user (devstack user) to the docker group. Try to enumerate containers:

`docker ps`

If that still does not fix the problem then you might want to change the permission of /var/run/docker.sock directly:

`sudo chown vagrant:vagrant /var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 0):

Check your kernel ( uname -a ) and make sure it is 3.8 or latest. Also, make sure you are on a 64bit Ubuntu ( X86_64 distribution ). The point is that the Docker daemon might not be starting (fails) because it is not supported on a 32 bit distribution.